# Why Hyperldger Fabirc v0.6 performance go down when block number increase?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm testing Hyperldger Fabric v0.6 in one server PC.
I wonder why the performance go down when block number increase?

PC Environment is as follows:

- OS：Cent
- process：Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1275 v5 @3.60GHz 64bit
- Memory：16GB

Fabric setting is as follows:

- 4 peer nodes
- 1 explorer node
- 1 membersrvc node

```
- CORE_PEER_VALIDATOR_CONSENSUS_PLUGIN=pbft  # noops, pbft
- CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_MODE=batch  
- CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_N=4
- CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_F=1
- CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_BATCHSIZE=1000  # only useful when in batch mode
- CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_TIMEOUT_REQUEST=4s
- CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_TIMEOUT_BATCH=2s
```